# BeautifulSoup - How to find a specific class name alone

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to find the `li` tags with a specific class name but not others? For example:

```
...
<li> no wanted </li>
<li class="a"> not his one </li>
<li class="a z"> neither this one </li>
<li class="b z"> neither this one </li>
<li class="c z"> neither this one </li>
...
<li class="z"> I WANT THIS ONLY ONE</li>
...
```

the code:

`bs4.find_all ('li', class_='z')`
returns several entries where there is a `"z"` and another class name.

How to find the entry with the class name `"z"`, alone ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to match the exact class name.

```
html = '''<li> no wanted </li>
<li class="a"> not his one </li>
<li class="a z"> neither this one </li>
<li class="b z"> neither this one </li>
<li class="c z"> neither this one </li>
<li class="z"> I WANT THIS ONLY ONE</li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

tags = soup.select('li[class="z"]')
print(tags)
```

The same result can be achieved using `lambda`:

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'li' and tag.get('class') == ['z'])
```

Output:

```
[<li class="z"> I WANT THIS ONLY ONE</li>]
```

---

Have a look at [Multi-valued attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes). You'll understand why `class_='z'` matches all the tags that have `z` in their class name.

> HTML 4 defines a few attributes that can have multiple values. HTML 5 removes a couple of them, but defines a few more. The most common multi-valued attribute is `class` (that is, a tag can have more than one CSS class). Others include `rel`, `rev`, `accept-charset`, `headers`, and `accesskey`. Beautiful Soup presents the value(s) of a multi-valued attribute as a list:
>
> ```
> css_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body"></p>')
> css_soup.p['class']
> # ["body"]
>
> css_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body strikeout"></p>')
> css_soup.p['class']
> # ["body", "strikeout"]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```py
data = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'z'})
print(data)
```

If you only want to get text:

```py
for a in data:
   print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with a filter function as in the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

```
def is_only_z(css_class):
    return css_class is not None and css_class == 'z'

bs4.find_all('li',class_=is_only_z)
```